# typeof returns "object" for `this`, "number" elsewhere

Tags: javascript

`typeof` evaluates to different strings when applied to the same value in different contexts.  For example, this is expected:

```
> typeof 5
'number'
```

...and yet, the `typeof` `5` when accessed via `this` is not the same:

```
> Number.prototype.foo = function () { return typeof this; };
[Function]
> (5).foo()
'object'
```

Just another (in)sanity check, to really, seriously verify that `this` *is* a number:

```
> Number.prototype.foo = function () { return [this + 1, typeof this]; };
[Function]
> (5).foo()
[ 6, 'object' ]
```

I've read through the MDN docs and the [ECMAScript spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) for `typeof`, and can't imagine how this is to be expected, nevermind correct.  Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: You should read up on the `this` variable and how it differs from other languages you are more familiar with. In both your examples, `this` refers to the language primitive.

Comment: Has nothing to do with typeof, it has to do with `this` and what it is.

Comment: `this + 1` is really `this.valueOf() + 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick here is that your test case changes 5 to an object.

Whenever you access a property on a primitive value(boolean, number or string), the primitive value is converted to an object of the appropriate type (Boolean, Number or String) and the property access is resolved on that object.

I have written more on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19979989/1669279) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20012914/1669279)

The correct method to show the type is:

```
Number.prototype.foo = function () { return typeof this.valueOf(); };
(5).foo() // "number"
```

Your sanity check converts the Object wrapper back to the primitive value when you do `this+1`:

```
(new Number(5)) + 1 // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `(5)` casts the primitive type `number` to a `Number` object.

Try adding a function like this:

```
Number.prototype.foo2 = function() { console.log(this); }
```

and you'll get a result like this in Chrome after you call `(5).foo2()`:

```
Number {foo: function, foo2: function}
    __proto__: Number
    [[PrimitiveValue]]: 5
```

Comment: It's not the parenthesis that cast `5` to a `Number`, but the method call. The parenthesis are there to force the parser to correctly interpret the `.` as a property lookup instead of decimal part separator (`obj.prop` vs `123.456`). `5.foo` is a syntax error.