# JavaScript native inheritance chain

Tags: javascript

```
          null
           ^
           |
         Object
           ^
           |
  String - Array - Boolean - Object - Number
     ^                         ^
     |                         |
"hello world"              { foo: 1 }
```

I would like to know if my inheritance scheme above is correct. I made it based it on tests like

```
console.log(typeof [].hasOwnProperty) // function
```

What I'm aslo curious about is if the `Object` part is correct. For example, `.hasOwnProperty()` is defined on the `Object.prototype`. So when you create an object literal like `{ foo: 1 }` above, I guess that the `{ foo: 1 }.hasOwnProperty` method is inherited from a base object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function getPrototypeChain(obj) {
    result = [];
    while (obj) {
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
        result.push(obj ? obj.constructor.name : "" + obj);
    }
    return result.join("--->");
}


getPrototypeChain({ foo: 1 });           // Object  ---> null
getPrototypeChain([]);                   // Array   ---> Object ---> null
getPrototypeChain(new String("hello"));  // String  ---> Object ---> null
getPrototypeChain(new Number(2));        // Number  ---> Object ---> null
getPrototypeChain(new Boolean(true));    // Boolean ---> Object ---> null
```

Keep in mind that `"hello world"` is technically a primitive that doesn't have any prototypes, only the string object (`new String("hello")`) has. The same goes for numbers and boolean values.

Comment: If the string primitive doesn't have a prototype, how can I access `console.log(typeof "hello world".hasOwnProperty) // function` ?

Comment: It's because of the `.` operator which will temporarily create an object for the string, applies whatever you want to apply (i.e. `hasOwnProperty`), and throws the object away again. But cannot do `Object.getPrototypeOf("hello")`, this will throw an error.

Comment: @Johan [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20636091/1669279) explains about Object wrappers and what happens when you call a method on a primitive value.

Answer (score 1):

By default, all the objects inherit the from Object. This means that they can use all the methods defined on the Object prototype.

The { foo: 1 }.hasOwnProperty is not inherited from a base object, for the simple reason that an object literal is an instance of Object; so it has the hasOwnProperty on the prototype of the Object constructor.

Consider the following:

```
var Person = function(name) { 
    this.name = name 
}

var p = new Person('Pavlos');
```

Now you can still use the hasOwnProperty method, but this time it is inherited form the base object, as you say. When you call

```
p.hasOwnProperty()
```

It will try to see if the method exist on the prototype of the Person constructor. If not, it will search in the prototype chain for a member with the hasOwnProperty name. This method exist on the prototype of the base Object constructor

Comment: Thanks, that straights out a lot. I'm afraid that I only can accept one answer, but I'll upvote this. No hard feelings